# "Error: could not find or load main class #" while opening groovy console

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

When I try to open groovyConsole.bat, I get the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class #

Tried the below to troubleshoot

1) Checked the env variable and gave the below

> java_home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
>
> Path: %java_home%\bin

2) Checked the Groovy env as well

> groovy_home: H:\Documents\Groovy-2.4.3
>
> Path: %groovy_home%\bin

3) Reinstalled java

The logs when I executed with `set DEBUG=1`

> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set
>   DIRNAME=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin\
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin\" ==
>   "" set DIRNAME=.\
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>"H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin\startGroovy.bat"
>   "H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin\" groovy.ui.Console
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
>   enabledelayedexpansion
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set
>   DIRNAME=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin\
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>shift
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set CLASS=groovy.ui.Console
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>shift
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/preinit.bat" call
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/preinit.bat"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set COMMAND_COM="cmd.exe"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
>   set COMMAND_COM="C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\WINDOWS\command.com" set
>   COMMAND_COM="C:\WINDOWS\command.com"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set FIND_EXE="find.exe"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe"
>   set FIND_EXE="C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\WINDOWS\command\find.exe"
>   set FIND_EXE="C:\WINDOWS\command\find.exe"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if not "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221" == "" goto have_JAVA_HOME
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "1" == "\" SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_22
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /C DIR
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"   2>&1  |
>   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\find.exe" /I /C "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"  1>nul
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if not errorlevel 1 goto
>   valid_JAVA_HOME_DIR
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set JAVA_EXE=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" goto valid_JAVA_HOME
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar" set TOOLS_JAR=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8" == "" set
>   GROOVY_HOME=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin..
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "8" == "\" SET
>   GROOVY_HOME=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set _SKIP=2
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set CP=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x-cp" set CP=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x-classpath" set CP=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x--classpath" set CP=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x" goto preview_check
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set PREV=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set REPLACE_PREVIEW=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x-pr" goto preview_enable
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x--enable-preview" goto
>   preview_enable
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>goto init
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set GROOVY_SCRIPT_NAME=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if not "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" goto
>   win9xME_args
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NT_args
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x" goto execute
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set
>   STARTER_CLASSPATH=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\lib\groovy-2.5.8.jar
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/init.bat" call
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/init.bat"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x" goto empty_cp
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set CP=.
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "x" == "x" goto after_cp
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set
>   STARTER_MAIN_CLASS=org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set
>   STARTER_CONF=H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set GROOVY_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=""
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set GROOVY_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=""
>   -Dgroovy.home="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if not "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar" == "" set
>   GROOVY_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=""
>   -Dgroovy.home="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8" -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set GROOVY_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=""
>   -Dgroovy.home="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8" -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar"
>   -Dgroovy.starter.conf="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set GROOVY_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=""
>   -Dgroovy.home="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8" -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar"
>   -Dgroovy.starter.conf="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf"
>   -Dscript.name=""
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>for /F "tokens=3" %g in ('call
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1 |
>   findstr /i "version"') do (SET JAVA_VERSION=%g )
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>(SET JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_221" )
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>for /F "useback tokens=*" %a in
>   ('"1.8.0_221"') do set JAVA_VERSION=%~a
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set JAVA_VERSION=1.8.0_221
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set JAVA_VERSION=1.8.0
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>set ADD_MODULES_OPT=--add-modules
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "1.8.0" GTR "1.8.0" set
>   JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
>   -Dhttp.proxyUser=sarulraj -Dhttp.proxyPassword=changethis -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=changethis -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=pit-wvrpnpd_j_co_uk.crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=vROps_fox.jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl # very verbose debug -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=foxvrops
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foxvrops -Dgroovy.jaxb=jaxb
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "1.8.0" GTR "1.8.0" if "" == "true"
>   set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=80
>   -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=changethis -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=changethis -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=pit-wvrpnpd_j_co_uk.crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=vROps_fox.jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl # very verbose debug -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=foxvrops
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foxvrops --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.module=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.file.attribute=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.file.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security.acl=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security.interfaces=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security.spec=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time.chrono=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time.format=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time.temporal=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.time.zone=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.function=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.zip=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.datatransfer/java.awt.datatransfer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.applet=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.color=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.desktop=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.dnd=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.dnd.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.geom=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.im.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.image=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.image.renderable=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.print=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.beans=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/java.beans.beancontext=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.instrument/java.lang.instrument=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.logging/java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/java.lang.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/java.rmi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/java.rmi.activation=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/java.rmi.dgc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/java.rmi.registry=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/java.rmi.server=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.border=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.windows=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.java2d=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if exist
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/postinit.bat" call
>   "C:\Users\cogsujarulraj/.groovy/postinit.bat"
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>"C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -Dprogram.name=""
>   -Dgroovy.home="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8" -Dtools.jar="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar"
>   -Dgroovy.starter.conf="H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf"
>   -Dscript.name="" -Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=changethis -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=changethis -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=pit-wvnpd_j_co_uk.crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=vROps_fox.jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl # very verbose debug -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=foxvrops
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foxvrops -classpath "H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\lib\groovy-2.5.8.jar"
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --main groovy.ui.Console
>   --conf "H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\conf\groovy-starter.conf" --classpath "."
>   Error: Could not find or load main class #
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" endlocal
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>if "" == "on" pause
>
> H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\bin>C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C exit /B 1

Comment: start `cmd` run command `set DEBUG=1` then try to start groovyconsole from the same cmd. show the log you get. PS: normally java and groovy home should be in upper case: `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @daggett, the env variables are in upper case, while mentioning here, I did with lower
I have edited description with the logs.

Comment: @Vishwa - Im just trying to open the groovy console, not executing any script

Comment: @SujinSamArulRaj , kindly check if the environment classpath variable set to point to an valid jar

Comment: @Vishwa, can you explain in detail of what to do?

Comment: I tried setting classpath to `H:\Documents\groovy-2.5.8\lib\groovy-2.5.8.jar`, still it throws the same error

Comment: retry the another version of groovy , download a fresh copy and then try. set class path again with new version of jar.

Comment: tried with `groovy 2.4.3`, still the same error.

Comment: you have something non standard in your batch `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl #` that triggers error.  everything started from `if "1.8.0" GTR "1.8.0" set JAVA_OPTS` could you show JAVA_OPTS env variable? also check if `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl #` line is in one of groovy batches (seems startGroovy.bat)

Comment: `-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=changethis -Dhttps.proxyHost=host -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=changethis -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=pit-wv_j_co_uk.crt -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=vROps_fox.jks -Djavax.net.debug=ssl # very verbose debug -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=foxvrops -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=foxvrops`

This is the JAVA_OPTS - @daggett

Comment: @daggett, I removed `# very verbose debug` from JAVA_OPTS, it's working now, Thanks:)

Comment: by default `JAVA_OPTS` not defined. other `JAVA_OPTS` parameters also could affect your java applications including groovy.